# How do I open two tabs in a split pane in iTerm?

Tags: macos, command-line, iterm, tabs

I have a split pane `iTerm` window [image: window]

I would like to have two tabs in the right "pane", (as opposed to total of three panes) but cannot figure out how to do this.

I lucked into this yesterday, for the first time ever and loved it, but can't seem to remember how it was done.

Anyone know the process for adding tabs to the right half pane?

Comment: Looks like it may be [impossible](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/iterm2-discuss/p8-b4mPvD2w). Although I swear I did it the other day...

Answer (score 9):

Really late answer, but you are probably looking for Cmd+D or Cmd+Shift+D, if I understand it correctly.
(still might be useful for some lost soul out there)

Comment: Not what I want. I want two tabs, not the right pane split into two. Your answer allows you two split the panes further, but not use tabs.

Answer (score 1):

I use [Better Snap Tool](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/bettersnaptool/id417375580?mt=12) to place two iTerm windows side-by-side, which can each have multiple tabs.

Here are a few keybinds:

- <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> opens a new window
- <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow</kbd>, a custom mapping, snaps left or right
- <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> switches between them
- <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> opens a new tab
- <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>/<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>to cycle through tabs (reversed with shift modifier)
- <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> closes a tab

[image]